# How to programmatically uncheck a checkbox in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've got two checkboxes and I need to uncheck the other checkbox if the first checkbox was clicked.
Right now if a user clicks on the second checkbox and then on the first one, it works. The other way around, however, it doesn't (both of them stay checked). Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
class UploadFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var c1 : CheckBox
    lateinit var c2 : CheckBox

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, container, false)

        c1 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)
        c2 = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2)
        c1.setOnClickListener { v -> switchCheckedBox(v) }
        c2.setOnClickListener { v -> switchCheckedBox(v) }

        return view
    }

    private fun switchCheckedBox(v : View) {
        when (v.id) {
            R.id.checkBox1 -> c2.isChecked = false
            R.id.checkBox2 -> c1.isSelected = false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want 1 of them to be checked in any case why don't you use radio buttons?

Comment: I thought about it, but I kinda want the checkbox design. If there's no way to fix my code, I will use radiobuttons

Comment: Looks like a typo: the second case is using `isSelected` but should be using `isChecked`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `RadioButton`s instead of checkboxes. When you put multiple `RadioButton`s inside a `RadioGroup`, only one of them can be checked at a time, the previously selected `RadioButton` in that `RadioGroup` will be unchecked.

xml code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

kotlin code:

```
        when {
        findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButton).isChecked -> {
            //when upper button is checked
        }
        findViewById<RadioButton>(R.id.radioButton2).isChecked -> {
            //when lower button is checked
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple typo. You call `c1.isSelected = false`, intead use `c1.isChecked = false`.

```
private fun switchCheckedBox(v : View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.checkBox1 -> c2.isChecked = false
        R.id.checkBox2 -> c1.isChecked = false
    }
}
```